# Evaluate the sum of $\log\tan k$, $k=1\dots87$

Tags: trigonometry

Evaluate the sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^{87}\ln(\tan k)$$

I first of all wrote them as ratios of $sine$ and and $cosine$ using the fact that $tan(x)$=$sin(x)$/$cos(x)$

Then I later use the co- function identity to rewite them in $sine$ only but I am stock with the evaluation:
$[$ln(sin1)$ $ln(sin2)$ $ln(sin3)$ ... $ln(sin86)$ $ln(sin87)$]$-$[$ln(sin89)$ $ln(sin88) ... $ln(sin4)$ $ln(sin3)

Comment: Hint: $\tan(x)\tan(90^\circ -x)=1$, so the sum of their logs is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{87}\log\tan k=\sum_{k=3}^{44}\log\left(\overbrace{\tan k\cdot\tan(90-k)}^{=1}\right)+\log\left(\tan1\cdot\tan2\cdot\tan45\right)=$$

$$=\log\left(\tan1\cdot\tan2\right)$$

Comment: my problem here is how can I properbly evaluate
[$ln(sin1)$+$ln(sin2)$]-$ln(sin89)$-$ln(sin88)$